# selnium and beutifulsoup scraper very inconsistent

Tags: python, api, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have made a scraper for a page on the stockx site. The program scrapes sales data from a model popup table. Parses out the sold price adds all of them together and gives the average sale price. The problem is that the program gives a range of averages every time I run it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from itertools import islice

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://stockx.com/supreme-patchwork-mohair-cardigan-multicolor")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/button').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[9]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a').click()
time.sleep(3)

while EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,'Load More')):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(55) > div > div > div > div.modal-body > div > button').click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break
    
src = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, features='html.parser')
table = soup.table
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
raw_price_data = list()
bs = list()
for row in islice(table_rows, 1, None):
    td = row.find_all('td')[1]
    raw_price_data.append(td.text[1:])
raw_price_data = list(map(int, raw_price_data))
Sum = sum(raw_price_data)
avg = Sum / len(raw_price_data)
total_sales = len(raw_price_data)

avg = round(avg, 2)
print(f'Total Sales:{total_sales}')
print(f'Average Profit:{avg}')
```

I've recently added the total sales list to tell me how many rows beutifulsoup scrapes and it is different every time just like I thought.

Total Sales:1390
Average Profit:402.29

Total Sales:990
Average Profit:400.05

Total Sales:2270
Average Profit:407.36

These are some results after running the program all different.
I'm new to python and webscraping any help is much appreciated.

This is what I've been able to code for using the undocumented API. The API variable I found using the network tab on dev tools. The PAYLOAD is the query parameters in for the same request I found. Although I was still unable to get the data I wanted in python just error codes.

```
import requests
from  urllib.parse import urlencode


headers = {
    'authority': 'stockx.com',
    'appos': 'web',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'authorization': '',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
    'appversion': '0.1',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://stockx.com/supreme-patchwork-mohair-cardigan-multicolor',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'if-none-match': 'W/^\\^c3f-9c/EjYGTDiuj1w0OlHbjycsHHYU^\\^',
}

PAYLOAD = {
    "state": "480",
    "currency": "USD",
    "limit": 203,
    "page": "1",
    "sort": "createdAt",
    "order": "DESC",
    "country": "US"
}

api = 'https://stockx.com/api/products/509c6166-53d4-49bf-9221-fc10cb298911/chart'
response = requests.get(f'{api}{urlencode(PAYLOAD)}', headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Comment: i have some questions if you could help? @baduker

Comment: How did you find the api where did you look for the information to connect?@baduker

Comment: did you use the unoffical api?

Comment: I found the API by inspecting the network traffic in the Developer Tool of my browser. Is it unofficial? Well, this is what they use on their backend, so no, but it's not documented and open, if that's what you mean by "official" API. Then I had to figure out where are those characters coming from in the API URL. Those happened to match with the SKU that I stumbled upon in the page source code. Then, put this all together and there you have it.

Comment: So I did some more research on finding undocumented APIs and think I am on the right track I found the API request in the networks tab of dev tools I think. Played with it a little to figure out what parameters I needed to load all the data in the table from the API to a browser tab. @baduker

Comment: I did it really simply compared to your example, but the code I used keeps giving me 403, 404, or 502 codes when running I think I'm close but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong in sending the request to the API. @baduker

Comment: First I didn’t copy any part of your answer. But I do have a follow question to your edit on your post. I’ve figured out how to fix the program but could u explain the regex lines that’s the only thing that’s standing out to me.

Answer (score 2):

How about ditching both `selenium` and `BeautifulSoup` and going for pure `requests`?

How? Well, there's an API for that webpage you're scraping. All you need is a product's `sku` number. How do you get it?

You comb through the product's page source code just to find out there's a bunch of `<script>` tags that have something that looks like a `JSON` data. Great, right?

Also, you realize the `sku` is in one of those tags and it's always between the `model` and the `color` values. Why not `regex` that thing out?

Then, drop the `sku` into the `API` url, parse the respone, and calculate the average.

Putting this all together:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests


PRODUCT_URL = "https://stockx.com/supreme-brushed-mohair-cardigan-black"
PRODUCT_NAME = " ".join(i.title() for i in PRODUCT_URL.split('/')[-1].split('-'))

PAYLOAD = {
    "start_date": "all",
    "end_date": "2020-10-24",
    "intervals": 100,
    "format": "highstock",
    "currency": "USD"
}
HEADERS = {
    "referer": PRODUCT_URL,
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 "
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
}


product_page = requests.get(PRODUCT_URL, headers=HEADERS).text
product_sku = "".join(re.findall(r'"sku":"(.+)","color', product_page))

api_url = f"https://stockx.com/api/products/{product_sku}/chart?"
response = requests.get(f"{api_url}{urlencode(PAYLOAD)}", headers=HEADERS).json()

print(f"{response['title']['text']} for {PRODUCT_NAME}:")
series = response["series"][0]["data"]
for item in series:
    timestamp, price = item
    human_readable_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(timestamp / 1000))
    print(f"{human_readable_date} - {price}")

print("-" * 25)
print(f"Average: {sum(i[1] for i in series) / len(series)} {PAYLOAD['currency']}")
```

This outputs:

```
Average price over time for Supreme Brushed Mohair Cardigan Black:
2020-10-22 17:18:19 - 250
2020-10-22 17:49:13 - 250
2020-10-22 18:20:07 - 250
2020-10-22 18:51:01 - 250
2020-10-22 19:21:56 - 250
2020-10-22 19:52:50 - 250
2020-10-22 20:23:44 - 250
2020-10-22 20:54:38 - 250
2020-10-22 21:25:33 - 250
2020-10-22 21:56:27 - 250
2020-10-22 22:27:21 - 250
2020-10-22 22:58:15 - 250
2020-10-22 23:29:10 - 250
2020-10-23 00:00:04 - 250
2020-10-23 00:30:58 - 250
2020-10-23 01:01:53 - 200
2020-10-23 01:32:47 - 219
2020-10-23 02:03:41 - 219
2020-10-23 02:34:35 - 219
2020-10-23 03:05:30 - 219
2020-10-23 03:36:24 - 219
2020-10-23 04:07:18 - 219
2020-10-23 04:38:12 - 219
2020-10-23 05:09:07 - 219
2020-10-23 05:40:01 - 219
2020-10-23 06:10:55 - 219
2020-10-23 06:41:50 - 219
2020-10-23 07:12:44 - 219
2020-10-23 07:43:38 - 219
2020-10-23 08:14:32 - 219
2020-10-23 08:45:27 - 219
2020-10-23 09:16:21 - 219
2020-10-23 09:47:15 - 219
2020-10-23 10:18:09 - 219
2020-10-23 10:49:04 - 219
2020-10-23 11:19:58 - 219
2020-10-23 11:50:52 - 219
2020-10-23 12:21:46 - 219
2020-10-23 12:52:41 - 219
2020-10-23 13:23:35 - 219
2020-10-23 13:54:29 - 219
2020-10-23 14:25:24 - 219
2020-10-23 14:56:18 - 219
2020-10-23 15:27:12 - 257
2020-10-23 15:58:06 - 257
2020-10-23 16:29:01 - 315
2020-10-23 16:59:55 - 315
2020-10-23 17:30:49 - 315
2020-10-23 18:01:43 - 315
2020-10-23 18:32:38 - 315
2020-10-23 19:03:32 - 315
2020-10-23 19:34:26 - 315
2020-10-23 20:05:21 - 315
2020-10-23 20:36:15 - 315
2020-10-23 21:07:09 - 315
2020-10-23 21:38:03 - 315
2020-10-23 22:08:58 - 315
2020-10-23 22:39:52 - 315
2020-10-23 23:10:46 - 315
2020-10-23 23:41:40 - 315
2020-10-24 00:12:35 - 315
2020-10-24 00:43:29 - 315
2020-10-24 01:14:23 - 315
2020-10-24 01:45:18 - 315
2020-10-24 02:16:12 - 315
2020-10-24 02:47:06 - 315
2020-10-24 03:18:00 - 315
2020-10-24 03:48:55 - 315
2020-10-24 04:19:49 - 315
2020-10-24 04:50:43 - 315
2020-10-24 05:21:37 - 315
2020-10-24 05:52:32 - 315
2020-10-24 06:23:26 - 315
2020-10-24 06:54:20 - 315
2020-10-24 07:25:14 - 315
2020-10-24 07:56:09 - 277
2020-10-24 08:27:03 - 277
2020-10-24 08:57:57 - 277
2020-10-24 09:28:52 - 277
2020-10-24 09:59:46 - 277
2020-10-24 10:30:40 - 277
2020-10-24 11:01:34 - 277
2020-10-24 11:32:29 - 277
2020-10-24 12:03:23 - 277
2020-10-24 12:34:17 - 277
2020-10-24 13:05:11 - 277
2020-10-24 13:36:06 - 277
2020-10-24 14:07:00 - 277
2020-10-24 14:37:54 - 277
2020-10-24 15:08:49 - 277
2020-10-24 15:39:43 - 277
2020-10-24 16:10:37 - 277
2020-10-24 16:41:31 - 277
2020-10-24 17:12:26 - 277
2020-10-24 17:43:20 - 277
2020-10-24 18:14:14 - 277
2020-10-24 18:45:08 - 277
2020-10-24 19:16:03 - 277
2020-10-24 19:46:57 - 277
2020-10-24 20:17:51 - 277
-------------------------
Average: 267.52 USD
```

Bouns:

> This works with any product url! XD

EDIT:

To get the response form the `activity` end point try this:

```
import re

import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode


PRODUCT_URL = "https://stockx.com/supreme-brushed-mohair-cardigan-black"
PRODUCT_NAME = " ".join(i.title() for i in PRODUCT_URL.split('/')[-1].split('-'))


HEADERS = {
    "referer": PRODUCT_URL,
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
    "x-requested-with": 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

PAYLOAD = {
    "state": "480",
    "currency": "USD",
    "limit": 10,
    "sort": "createdAt",
    "order": "DESC",
    "country": "US"
}


product_page = requests.get(PRODUCT_URL, headers=HEADERS).text
product_sku = "".join(re.findall(r'"sku":"(.+)","color', product_page))

api_url = f"https://stockx.com/api/products/{product_sku}/activity?"
response = requests.get(f'{api_url}{urlencode(PAYLOAD)}', headers=HEADERS).json()

for item in response:
    print(f"{item['chainId']} - shoe size: {item['shoeSize']} at {item['amount']} {item['localCurrency']}")
```

Output:

```
13451189134512711854 - shoe size: M at 250.6639 USD
13454493613262000326 - shoe size: XL at 305 USD
13454719168825677535 - shoe size: M at 250.451 USD
13454432070832901351 - shoe size: XL at 321.4601 USD
13454370874521531956 - shoe size: XL at 315 USD
13454370577625857582 - shoe size: XL at 320 USD
13450796013705700403 - shoe size: M at 240 USD
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So I finally got it.
I decided to throw out beautiful soup and selenium and just to use request and urllib after reading @badukers post thanks again. Even though badukers method helped me allot to get on the right track the API he used did not give me the data I was looking for the average profit. After some research on undocumented APIs I was able to look through the dev tools to find the request for the API I needed the /activity not the /chart API. After finding the right API I had to figure out how to use the arguments, so I played with the url until I got all 203 sales. At that point it was easy moving that to python just had to make sure I chose the correct arguments and needed header. One thing I'm still not sure about is what the user agent means and why the script fails if it's not included but everything else can be excluded.

Here's my code for gathering the total average profit for the cardigan item I was looking for.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode


API_URL = 'https://stockx.com/api/products/509c6166-53d4-49bf-9221-fc10cb298911/activity?'


PAYLOAD = {
    "state": "480",
    "currency": "USD",
    "limit": 203,
    "page": "1",
    "sort": "createdAt",
    "order": "DESC",
    "country": "US"
}

HEADERS = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': 'https://stockx.com/supreme-patchwork-mohair-cardigan-multicolor',
}

response = requests.get(f'{API_URL}' + urlencode(PAYLOAD), headers=HEADERS).json()


ProductActivity = response['ProductActivity']
amount = [i['amount'] for i in ProductActivity]
tprofit = list()
for price in amount:
    profit = price - 188
    tprofit.append(profit)
    print(f'Sale Price:Profit--------------{price}:{profit}')
print('-'*40)
ave = sum(tprofit)/len(amount)
print(f'Raw Sale Average--------------{ave}')
```

I plan on adding to this so it can be used for any product. If anybody out there knows about the user agent or how I can make sure it loads all the data even if there is a new sale let me know. Because I hard coded in the number of results in the program if there is another sale ill miss that next time I run the script.